# MS Access query to toggle between records with true and all records

Tags: ms-access

I have a query which returns, among other things, an Active flag: true for Active, false for not Active. There is an Active checkbox control on the form. The default is Checked. When the checkbox is checked I need the query to return only the records with Active = true. When the checkbox is not checked, I need all records returned.

I have been trying to set a criteria on the Active field in the query like this:

```
IIf([Forms]![myForm]![chkActive]=True,True,)
IIf([Forms]![myForm]![chkActive]=True,True, True or False)
IIf([Forms]![myForm]![chkActive]=True,True,([MyQuery]![Active])=True Or ([MyQuery]![Active])=False)
```

The reasoning is that if the chkActive is checked, the IIf returns True and otherwise it returns some indication that I want all records.
The Checked part seems to work fine.  And if I use something like:

```
IIf([Forms]![myForm]![chkActive]=True,True,False)
```

I can switch between seeing the True records and the False records. I would like to switch between seeing the True records and All the records.

The other thing is that the query returns nothing when the form opens. I think the value of `[Forms]![myForm]![chkActive]` does not exist at the time when the query is needed to populate the form. However, the query seems to access the  `[Forms]![myForm]![chkActive]` fine when it is called from the `OnClick` event of the chkActive. It gets called by:

```
DoCmd.Requery
```

Any useful insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the value of your control as a column inside the query:

```
FilterControl1: [Forms]![myForm]![chkActive]
```

and then set the criteria for this column to `In ([Active], false)`.
The expression is true if either the control and the column match or if *false* is selected. *false* works as the *all* selector.
This may look a bit cryptical, but it also works well for other data types. Say you have a combobox with IDs and added ID = -1, Text ='<all>' with a UNION in the query.
Then `ColumnN: [ControlName]`, Criteria: `IN ([column], -1)` works alike to filter either the selection or -1 for all.

I can also confirm that the filter does not work on loading. I guess that's just Access. A `Me.Requery` in `Form_Load` seems to work ok.